# how to get nested array value from jquery serializeArray()

Tags: jquery

I'm getting nested array value from serializeArray() jquery function.i obtain this single value but i can not get array value.How to get this.Please help.

```
var serialized = myform.serializeArray();
var dataObj = {};
$(serialized).each(function (i, field) {                    
     dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
  });
console.log(dataObj);
```

After i see output this console : like this

```
Name: "test"
StudentViewModelList[0].Marks: "10"
StudentViewModelList[0].Serial: "1"
StudentViewModelList[1].Marks: "5"
StudentViewModelList[1].Serial: "2"
```

i get Name value using

```
   console.log(dataObj.Name);
```

But i can not get below this code value undefined

```
   console.log(dataObj.StudentViewModelList[0].Marks);
```

How can i get value.Please help.

Comment: can you provide your `serialized` value ?  because you just set `Name` in `dataObj`, you are not assign `StudentViewModelList` array to your `dataObj` object

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yap,this is serialized data.But how to get this StudentViewModelList  value

Comment: please show your `myform.serializeArray()` value what data contains

Comment: Name: "test"
StudentViewModelList[0].Marks: "10"
StudentViewModelList[0].Serial: "1"
StudentViewModelList[1].Marks: "5"
StudentViewModelList[1].Serial: "2"